# Expected value question solution

Tags: probability, expected-value

We flip 2 coins:Our random value is the number of heads

Possible values: $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline &TT& HT ~~~ TH & HH\\\hline
X&       0&       1&       2\\ \hline
p(X=x)&  0.25&    0.5&     0.25\\\hline\end{array}$$

To get the expected value we find this sum : $$\begin{align}\left.\sum_{x=0}^2 \middle(x\cdot p(X=x)\right)~&=~ 0\cdot 0.25+1\cdot 0.5+2\cdot 0.25\\[1ex]&=0.5+0.5\\[1ex]&=1\end{align}$$

Is that correct? I just started studying probabilities so go easy on me.

Comment: Yes, it is correct (assuming the coins are fair).  Another way to see it is to note that the expected number of heads must equal the expected number of tails and that the two must sum to $2$.

Comment: You would notice in how you originally wrote your post, the stars were not appearing.  That is because if you want to type something *with italics* you use the stars around it to write it like `*with italics*`.  Similarly **bold words** are written as `**bold words**` with two stars surrounding them.  In order to have math appear correctly, have a look at how I edited this and take a look at this [MathJax primer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to get an idea how to properly typeset equations with MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Your table seems accidentally shifted.  I believe that row labels $X$ and $P[X=x]$ should shift to the left, to leave room for four numerical values in each of the two rows.

Comment: @Michael I hadn't put much thought into how the OP had originally formatted their table, just went and put how it appeared on the edit page before the parser got a hold of it and typeset an equivalent table.  I've gone ahead and taken your observation into account and edited further.

Comment: @JMoravitz : I couldn't help making a new column and making hte $X$ labels correct.  =)

Comment: Oh you just undid what I did, I think to make the X labels correct by changing the labels not the numbers.

Comment: @Michael as for having HT and TH in separate columns, I disagree with that, as the purpose to try to treat the different values of $X$ as the index is common.  Else, you'll have the third row not make much sense as $p(X=1)$ is $0.5$ but in your edit you'd have two columns each labeled as $X=1$ each of which with the implication that $p(X=1)$ was $0.25$.  If the third row were instead written as $p(\{HT\})$ in the one column and $p(\{TH\})$ in the other, then I'd agree with separating them.  Regardless, this discussion of presentation is a bit off topic.

Comment: Either way is fine, now the table makes sense.  I was thinking of the sample space as $$S = \{(T,T), (T,H), (H,T), (H,H)\}$$ and  random variable $X:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $X(T,T)=0$, $X(T,H)=1$, $X(H,T)=1$, $X(H,H)=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at the problem is to observe that flipping 2 fair once coins or flipping twice a single fair coin is the same. So the number of H (or T) is distributed with a Binomial law

$$X\sim Bin(n;p)=Bin(2;\frac{1}{2})$$

with mean $\mathbb{E}[X]=n\cdot p=1$